# Conditional Distribution Definition

Tags: probability-theory

Given a specific sample space and two events $A, B$,

$P(A\mid B) = \dfrac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$ if $P(B) > 0$

Likewise for two jointly distributed discrete random variables $X,Y$,

$P_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y) = \dfrac{P_{X,Y}(x,y)}{P_Y(y)}$ if $P_Y(y) > 0$

However for the case of $P_Y(y) = 0$, it is defined as $P_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y) = 0$. Why is it equals to $0$? And why is there a need to define it in such a way?

Comment: When $P_Y(y)=0$, $P_{X|Y}(x|y)$ can be defined as anything fixed. Usually in a elementary probability course, such case is not mentioned. It would become clearer when you learn the conditional expectations in the [abstract setting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Formal_definition).

Comment: yes i have only took the introductory course, i will be learning more next semester :)

Comment: I do not agree with $P_{X|Y}(x|y)=0$ as definition for special case $P_Y(y)=0$. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then it is more natural and suitable to go for $P_{X|Y}(x|y)=P_X(x)$.

Comment: @drhab: You can of course argue that one *could* define $P_{X|Y}(x|y)=P_X(x)$ for $P_Y(y)=0$ so that one has the consistent equality $P(X\in A|Y=y)=P(X\in A)$ when $X,Y$ are independent. However, OP is asking *why* it is defined as $0$. On the other hand, it is usually left as undefined in lots of textbooks on probability.

Comment: @Jack Yes. Well, I admit that actually I have no good answer on the question "why $=0$?". I cannot find a proper reason for that and in my view it is better to say that it is not determined, or undefined if you like. This however without excluding that suitable values can be chosen.

Comment: Who defines this as zero?

Comment: From the book "Mathematical statistics and data analysis" by Rice J.A.

Comment: Indeed. Rather odd choice.

Answer (score 0):

As "pseudo-definition" of $P(A\mid B)$ you can also restrict to only the relation:$$P(A\mid B)P(B)=P(A\cap B)$$
In special case $P(B)=0$ we have automatically $P(A\cap B)=0$ so the factor $P(A\mid B)$ is indetermined, and you can somehow "choose" a suitable value.

The convenience of this shows up for instance if  $X,Y$ are independent random variables and $P(Y=y)=0$.

Then we can we can still make the suitable choice: $$P(X\in A\mid Y=y)=P(X\in A)$$ which gives expression of the independence.